# Handle MVC Validation Error Messages on AJAX return

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

**Model**:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var modelErrors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (var modelError in modelState.Errors)
            {
                modelErrors.Add(modelError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        return Json(new { success = false,  responseText = modelErrors[0] });
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);               

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form            
    return View(ModelState);
}
```

**View:**

```
<div id="divError" class="alert alert-danger collapse">
    <a id="linkClose" class="close" hred="#">&times;</a>
    <div id="divErrorText"></div>
</div>
```

**javaScript:**

```
$('#btnRegister1').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/Register',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            Email: $('#txtEmail').val(),
            Password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
            ConfirmPassword: $('#txtConfirmPassword').val(),
            __RequestVerificationToken: token,
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#successModal').modal('show');
            }, 
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
            $('#divError').show('fade');
        }                
    });            
});
```

This code is used for displaying **MVC** validation errors using AJAX. Code runs as expected for the AJAX `success` function but is failing to hit AJAX `error` function code and its rather running `success` function even when there are validation errors and it should be running AJAX `error` function code.

Can someone please guide. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you have validation errors, you need to return an appropriate statuscode, a 400 or 422. You are returning a 200, which is a success statuscode and that's why your ajax call isn't considered an error.

Comment: That's sounds correct but I've `success = false` here: `return Json(new { success = false,  responseText = modelErrors[0] });` in my `Controller` code. Wonder what that does. (-;

Comment: Your `success=false` is a key inside your json payload coming down to your client. It is a bit contradictory if you look at it. You are returning a a successful response code but then in the payload you are saying it wasn't successful. Just return a `BadRequest(modelErrors)` instead of `json`

Comment: @JohanP Why are you answering the question in a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JohanP in comments above.

Following solved it.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var modelErrors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (var modelError in modelState.Errors)
            {
                modelErrors.Add(modelError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return Json(modelErrors[0]);
    }
```